# Can I have a vector of polymorphic values under a fixed sized assumption?

Tags: c++, c++11, polymorphism, stdvector, virtual-functions

Consider the below code, a derived class replaces a virtual member function with a variant of the function, but does not add any new member variables.  Values of Base and Derived are added to a common container, std::vector and as expected the Derived value is sliced.  However by copying the representation in memory of the Derived value into the container the value is in effect only partially sliced.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Base {
public:
    Base() = default;
    Base(float arg) : a{ arg } {};

    virtual float doSomething(float b) const { return a + b; }

    float a;
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    Derived() = default;
    Derived(float a) : Base{ a } {};

    float doSomething(float b) const { return a - b; }
};

int main()
{
    Base b{ 1.0f };
    Derived d{ 1.0f };

    std::cout << sizeof(b) << ", " << sizeof(d) << '\n';  // 8, 8

    std::vector<Base> v{ b, d };  // d is sliced
    std::cout << v[0].doSomething(2.0f) << '\n';  // 3
    std::cout << v[1].doSomething(2.0f) << '\n';  // 3 as d was sliced

    memcpy(&v[1], &d, sizeof(d));  // Copy the representation of d over to v[1]
    std::cout << v[1].doSomething(2.0f) << '\n';  // now -1
}
```

The size of the values is 8 due to the pointer to the virtual function table and this is how to above polymorphism is being realised.  The type of v[1] is always Base, so if Derived added a new member function it wouldn't be possible to call it.  In effect v[1] is still sliced to Base but with the reimplemented member functions of Derived.

Under the assumption that Base is essentially POD but with added virtual member functions, all of which are const i.e. memory copyable, and that Derived only reimplements those member functions:

1. Does the above code fall into undefined behaviour?
2. If so is there a way to implement this without the memcpy or equivalent in a way that would be defined behaviour?
3. If this is a common pattern, what is it called?

Comment: For polymorphism to work, you need either a *reference* or a *pointer* to the object, using the base type. So e.g. `Base* pointer = new Derived(1.0f);`

Comment: Note that you print `sizeof(b)` *twice*.

Comment: There is also a problem if the vector is ever resized, the value will be sliced again. `polymorphic_value` is similar but on the heap

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks, I've corrected sizeof(b) and am aware of how polymorphism is intended to work, I could have written (&v[1])->doSomething(2.0f).  At the moment I am using a vector of shared_ptr's which works just fine, but for my use case is far less efficient than if I manually implement polymorphism via a vector of structs and my own table of function pointers.

Comment: @Artyer good point about the std::vector resizing.  This could be fixed by using my own copy / move constructors thus enforcing the POD assumption.

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to ask about the actual underlying problem you have, and we could possibly help you with that instead? Also "less efficient" how? Have you measured that (in an optimized build) to be one of the top two (or possibly three) bottlenecks in your program?

Comment: I'm using a vector as a stack of transformations of various types, eg rotation, translation, but perhaps not one representable by a matrix.  I need to apply this stack of transformations to different values in turn and I need to clear the stack and rebuild it repeatedly.  The complexity of my algorithm is worstcase n^2 with n the number of transformations.  With my current vector of shared_ptr<Base> and with n about 400 this becomes the bottleneck with an optimised build and only 100 in debug.

Comment: Sorry, I'm aware that's not much help, but asking about the full problem is tricky, perhaps I should have said that I want to iterate quickly over a container of values with polymorphism only applied to member variables and i need to build/destroy/rebuild efficiently as well (although it's the iteration that's the primary bottleneck).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with your questions:

> 1. Does the above code fall into undefined behaviour?

Yes. Use of `memcpy` on *non-trivially copyable* objects is undefined behavior.

> 2. If so is there a way to implement this without the memcpy or equivalent in a way that would be defined behaviour?

Yes, there is. It will still use polymorphism - not for the object that you store but rather for its field(s).

> 3. If this is a common pattern, what is it
>    called?

Yes. The proposed solution has a name. It is called ***Strategy-Pattern*** or ***State-Pattern*** (depending on what is exactly the purpose of what you are trying to achieve).

Here is an equivalent code (in a way) to what you try to achieve:

### The different strategies

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual ~Base() {}
    virtual float doSomething(float a, float b) const { return a + b; }
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    float doSomething(float a, float b) const override { return a - b; }
};
```

### The Actual Type to be stored

```
class RealType {
    float a;
    const Base* strategy;
public:
    // just for the example, could be implemented in other ways
    const static Base BaseStrategy;
    const static Derived DerivedStrategy;

    RealType(float val, const Base& s): a(val), strategy(&s) {}
    float doSomething(float b) const { return strategy->doSomething(a, b); }
};

const Base RealType::BaseStrategy {};
const Derived RealType::DerivedStrategy {};
```

### Usage Example

```
int main()
{
    RealType b{ 1.0f, RealType::BaseStrategy };
    RealType d{ 1.0f, RealType::DerivedStrategy };

    std::cout << sizeof(b) << ", " << sizeof(d) << '\n';  // size of pointer

    std::vector<RealType> v{ b, d };  // no slicing
    std::cout << v[0].doSomething(2.0f) << '\n';  // 3
    std::cout << v[1].doSomething(2.0f) << '\n';  // -1 as no slicing

    v[0] = v[1]; // copies both the value stored in v[1] as well as the strategy
    std::cout << v[0].doSomething(2.0f) << '\n';  // now -1 with v[0]
}
```

Code: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e1b102bc70427177

Comment: Thank you Amir, that's very thorough, helpful and exactly what I should use.  As you say, it loses the polymorphism on the object.  But as it doesn't make sense for constructors to be virtual, any container of polymorphic objects as values is going to have limited functionality (eg no copy constructor/assignment without slicing).

Answer (score 0):

Amir's answer was the one I needed.  However for completeness I'll now fill in what I actually wanted when I asked the question.

It is possible to store values of differing types in a std::vector just as long as these types themselves are suitably wrapped in a common type, essentially a form of type erasure.  The container internally would have a buffer of a fixed length and with the proper alignment, e.g. using std::aligned_storage.  You would then implement copy/move semantics using placement new and a template for each type with a clone function.

An obvious enhancement would be to allow for types too large for the buffer to be held by a unique_ptr.  From this perspective the container is really a wrapper around a unique_ptr with a small buffer optimisation thrown in.

I plan to implement this as an exercise for myself, I'll edit this answer if/when I get the chance.